# How to scan a column for a certain word and when triggered, remove the first 4 characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hey everyone so here is my setup

[image]

My issue is regarding the "C" column and how to remove the "2nd|" and "3rd|" portions so it ONLY shows "Mikes Auto Shop" "Carls Auto Repair" etc

Like this

[image: http://imgur.com/a/ddpYq]

Comment: What's wrong with a simple worksheet formula using right or mid?  What have you tried and where have you run into problems?

Comment: `FIND` the position of the | bar in the text (won't be the 4th character if it says `10th|`), get the `LEN`gth of the whole text string.  Return everything to the `RIGHT` of the Length minus the Find position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a formula in `D2` will do the trick

```
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-4)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/375502-remove-first-letter-each-cell-column.html

on the forum here they mention that you can use =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1), for you it would look more like =RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-1) and you would place it in the D column and then just grap the bottom right hand corner and drag it down the will give you all the values you need in the D column, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If there is only sometimes a prefix or if it can be larger than 9, you can use:

```
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-IFERROR(FIND("|",C2),0))
```